# Pricing Assets in the S&P Dynamic Asset Exchange

Tags: asset-pricing, dynamic, asset, exchange

I am attempting to recreate the S&P Dynamic Asset Exchange using the methodology outlined in [this paper](http://www.spindices.com/documents/methodologies/methodology-sp-dynamic-asset-exchange.pdf).

I am struggling to 'normalize' the prices of the assets properly.  On page 6 of the aforementioned paper,

Price A(t) = Price of asset A normalized to equal 100 on the last trading day of the preceding year

Price B(t) = Price of asset B normalized to equal 100 on the last trading day of the preceding year

--
What methodology is implied for 'normalize' -- the standard Random Variable normalization? (Random Variable - Mean)/(Standard Deviation)?  Or is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case no fancy normalization techniques are implied. At least from what I understand from the cited part, they just scale the variables so that they are equal to 100 in the base period (end of preceding year) - something like computing a [deflator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflator), commonplace in macro analysis.

Comment: Hi Karol,

Thank you for the answer.  So, just to verify what you are saying: if the final return on the last trading day of the year was equal to 500, I would subtract 400 from all of the data points going forward?  So, 12/31/2010 return is 500 -- I would subtract 400 from the return for the next trading day, say, 1/1/2011?

If this is what you are describing, I have actually tried this and I have run into a number of problems.  Primarily, I have run into negative returns (after they have been 'normalized'), which in turn causes problems at the ln(Price B / Price A) -- ln is undefined <0.

Comment: Are you talking about returns or price levels? Your question and comment differ in that regard. And no, I had another procedure in mind - just try to adjust the variable through multiplying by a scaling factor. E.g. $$P_{t_0}=25 \wedge P_{t_{+1}} = 30 \Rightarrow P_{t_0}^*=100 \wedge P_{t_{+1}}^* = {100\over25} \times30=120$$ At least that's what I think they meant by *normalizing*.

Comment: Thank you, Karol!

Your answer seems reasonable to me -- and, importantly, results in valid data points (i.e. no negative data).  Approaching this from a statistical background, in a problem that uses correlation, covariance, std, I assumed normalization in the sense of fitting the data to a normal distribution.

Regarding Returns vs. Price Levels: it is my understanding that the 'Price', in this particular formula, is a function of the daily returns of various indices -- in my case, I am using the S&P 10 Year U.S. Treasury Note Futures Total Return Index to derive my Price B.

Answer (score -1):

On page 6 of the document there is the formula "Ct_DeltaAB = Equation #1 evaluated for changes in Price A and Price B". How can I know what the changes are in Price A and Price B? I know the correlation between A and B but that does not mean that I can derive the changes of A and B. How do I solve this problem?

Rick

Comment: This needs to be [a separate question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), not an answer.